# Access switch declared in XML via java

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, switch-statement

I've created a switch in XML. It'switch is created as being checked.

I've gotten a boolean to save even when the app is restarted, all I need is the switch to match the boolean when the app is launched. I can't seem to figure out how to change this.

Will removing the `android:checked="true(or false)"` let me edit the code when the app is started, or does it not matter?

I've tried using an if-else statement to set the switch to the correct position when onCreate() is started, but that simply makes the application crash.

Here is my XML:

```
<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/SwitchName"
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dBellButton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="onToggleClicked" 
    android:checked="true" />
```

And here's my onCreate() method:

```
MediaPlayer dBell;
boolean vibeOn;

Switch switchConv = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    dBell = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.doorbell);

    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    vibeOn = pref.getBoolean("vibeRemember", true);

if (vibeOn = true) {
        switchConv.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        switchConv.setChecked(false);
    }
}
```

I figured the if-else statement is what is making the application crash at creation, but commenting out this block didn't fix the problem. So, I also commented out `Switch switchConv = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);`. Commenting out both of these blocks allows the code to be run successfully.

I'm wondering if my `findViewById` is what's causing the problem.

Is there another way to reference my switch in XML through my .java?

Thanks!

Nathan

Comment: Can you provide your Stacktrace please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private Switch switchConv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
   super.onCreate(bundle);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
switchConv = (Switch)this.findViewById(R.id.switch1);

SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
switchCon.setChecked(pref.getBoolean("vibeRemember", true));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to setContentView first before declaring the elements. Move your switch initialization after the setContentView.

And also **if (vibeOn = true)** to **if (vibeOn)**

Does it ring a bell?  You are using assignment operator instead of comparator. And also boolean can directly be used without comparator.

Answer (score 0):

You can't statically declare view, because you didn't yet call `setContentView()`. You have to declare all the views after you set content view:

```
Switch switchConv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {

    ...
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    switchConv = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Switch switchConv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    .......
    switchConv = (Switch)this.findViewById(R.id.switch1);

}
```

This worked for me.